# How to write IPTables policy to affect multiple ranges in a group?

Tags: iptables, firewall

I am trying to block the entire Internet on all ports, but allow a multiple ranges to connect on specific ports. I want this ruleset to apply to outbound connections as well (using `REJECT` instead of `DROP`) as to prevent identification attacks.

```
*filter

# Allow all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

# Accept all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow all network traffic
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT

# Allow all SSH
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT


# Permitted web connections
-A INPUT -s 8.4.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport http  -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 8.8.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport http  -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 8.4.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport https -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 8.8.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport https -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -s 8.4.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport http  -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s 8.8.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport http  -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s 8.4.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport https -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s 8.8.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport https -j ACCEPT

# Reject all web not to or from a safe server
-A INPUT  -p tcp --dport http  -j DROP
-A INPUT  -p tcp --dport https -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport http  -j REJECT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport https -j REJECT


# Drop all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed
-A INPUT   -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP

COMMIT
```

The drawback with my very strict policy is the verbosity of adding an additional range. Each range takes four lines of policy to work. Inbound/HTTP, Inbound/HTTPS, Outbound/HTTP, Outbound/HTTP. It's a huge pain to keep straight.

What I would like it something like this:

```
# Pseucode
*group webservers
8.8.0.0/24
8.4.0.0/24

*filter
-A INPUT -s webservers -p tcp --dport http  -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s webservers -p tcp --dport http  -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s webservers -p tcp --dport http  -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s webservers -p tcp --dport http  -j ACCEPT
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try using [ipsets](http://ipset.netfilter.org)

> If you want to
>
> - store multiple IP addresses or port numbers and match against the collection by iptables at one swoop;
> - dynamically update iptables rules against IP addresses or ports without performance penalty;
> - express complex IP address and ports based rulesets with one single iptables rule and benefit from the speed of IP sets
>
> then ipset may be the proper tool for you.

Worth noting that:

> IP sets are a framework inside the Linux kernel, which can be
>   administered by the ipset utility

And yes, the website looks like it hasn't been updated since 1996. For some reason computer security news sources and low-level software / firmware project webpages look like that a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try sending all the traffic from certain ranges to a custom chain, then each port-related accept becomes a single line:

```
iptables -N CUSTOM

iptables -I INPUT 1 -s 8.4.0.0/24 -j CUSTOM
iptables -I INPUT 2 -s 8.8.0.0/24 -j CUSTOM
etc.

iptables -A CUSTOM - p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A CUSTOM - p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
etc.
```

Packets from the source range(s) sent to the `CUSTOM` chain that don't match an `ACCEPT` there will come back to the `INPUT` chain for handling (ie, `DROP`ping) with all the rest of the unwanted traffic.